# Force servertime with Date for all operations when using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, date, timer

Im using Opencart and im using a Auction plugin which has a countdown timer. When the timer ends the auction is done. problem: The timer relies on the visitors clock. So for some the auction ends in 1 minute and for others in 2 minutes. It can even be abused by setting the clock a few hours in the past.

Is there a way to force all operations in opencart to rely on the server clock?

I tried the following code but it crashes the page where the auctions run, but works fine on a empty page. This code forces js to use servertime.

```
<?php
$now = date("Y-n-d-H-i-s", time());

echo '
var servDateArray=\''.$now.'\'.split(\'-\');
var Date=new Date(Number(servDateArray[0]),Number(servDateArray[1]),Number(servDateArray[2]),Number(servDateArray[3]),Number(servDateArray[4]),Number(servDateArray[5]));
document.write(Date);
</script>
';
?>
```

Im absolutly lost and im hoping theres a way to force the whole site to use servertime.

Please note im a newbie and it took me days of googling to get this far.

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

On client-side: calculate the time-difference between the server and the client. When displaying the time take that different in account.

```
var serverDate = new Date(2013,12,06,0,0,0);
var closeDate = new Date(2013,12,06,0,1,0);
var clientDate = new Date();
var timeDiff = clientDate - serverDate;

$('#timediff').html(timeDiff);
setInterval(function() {
    var remainingMillisecs = closeDate - (new Date()) + timeDiff;
    var remainingSeconds = remainingMillisecs / 1000;
    $('#remaining').html(parseInt(remainingSeconds));
}, 1000);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7b3AC/

I assume the auction is performed server-side, so there you really should check if the auction isn't closed when someone posts a bid.